# Get and set codec for QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm under Windows and I supposed the default codec for QString is `GBK`, but I have to send some content to a Linux platform which doesn't support `GBK`. I'm sending some CJK content so I decided to use `UTF8`.

How can I get what codec I'm using for QString and set the codec for it ?

Here's the line:

```
packet = packet.arg(MAC, operation, text_type, text.toUtf8());
```

I'm trying to insert some CJK `text` to a normal QString.

Comment: Did you read documentation about QTextCodec ?

Comment: I'd avoid any default QByteArray/char* literal to Unicode (which QString uses) conversions and use explicit convert with QString::fromUtf8(), QTextCodec etc.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Em..., I tried `QString text_utf = QString(text_old.toUtf8())` and send `text_utf` to the android tablet but displays stray code. I don't know whether it's my encoding problem or the android tablet's decoding problem.

Comment: @CDC thing you wrote does exactly nothing. This constructor http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#QString-8 is opposition to `toUtf8()`. Show more code how your communication or saving data looks like.

Comment: "QString text_utf = QString(text_old.toUtf8())" - this code is doing nothing. Because QString keeps data in unicode(16). Try QByteArray text_utf = text_old.toUtf8(); and send text_utf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to think about the codec. What about:

```
QString::fromLocal8Bit(myInput).toUtf8();
```

This should work fine. If you really need to manually mess with the codec look for QTextCodec.